# Растолкуйте за Partial и Render в ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Начал изучать asp.net mvc по книге Адама Фримена и столкнулся с частичными представлениями, так вот есть

```
@Html.Partial()
@Html.RenderAction()
@Html.RenderPartial()
```

Так вот, какая разница в этих хелперах? По-гуглив и прочитав об этих хелперах, я окончательно запутался. Так вот, хотел спросить у знающих и практикующих, когда и в каких случаях они используются??

Comment: вот здесь описана разница   
http://shiftoffproblem.com/mvc-razor-visualize-difference/

Comment: @Eikhner Добавь в ответ, я отмечу как правильный ответ. Спасибо за ссылку.

Comment: да это не ответ , совет скорее всего . Не нужно ничего отмечать ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если использовать приставку Render, то результаты выполнения сразу встраиваются в выходной поток. С приставкой Render - это void метод, поэтому в коде мы должны закрывать строку точкой с запятой и не можем использовать @ перед вызовом. Правильный вызов RenderPartial(RenderAction  аналогично):

```
@{
     Html.RenderPartial("View");
}
```

Без приставки Render Html.Partial (как и Html.Action) - возвращает html разметку. Разметка хранится в буфере, а потом также встраивается в выходной поток. Поэтому первый способ немного эффективнее.

Правильный синтаксис (без точки с запятой):

```
@Html.Partial("View")
```